# Proving DeMorgan's Law in IPC with Weak Law of Excluded Middle

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am trying to show that $\neg (A \land B)$ implies $\neg A \lor \neg B$ in Intuitionistic Propositional Calculus (IPC) with the added inference rule of ''Weak excluded middle," which is that you can invoke $\neg \neg P \lor \neg P$.

My idea is to assume assume $\neg \neg A \lor \neg A$. If $\neg A$, the result follows. So we have to deal with $\neg \neg A$. So assume either $\neg \neg B \lor \neg B$. If $\neg B$, the result follows. So we have $\neg \neg A \land \neg \neg B$. Assumedly, one can prove $\neg (\neg A \lor \neg B)$ from this, and then finish the proof. But I am stuck on that last step of showing  $\neg \neg A \land \neg \neg B \Rightarrow \neg (\neg A \lor \neg B)$. I know this follows from the truth tables, but I am trying to do this just using the inference rules of the system I'm working in.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to MSE!

You have exactly the right idea.

We want to show that, under weak LEM, $\lnot(A \land B)$ implies $\lnot A \lor \lnot B$. How do we do this? Well, just as you've said, by weak LEM we may assume $\lnot A \lor \lnot \lnot A$ and $\lnot B \lor \lnot \lnot B$.
Since the $\lnot A$ and $\lnot B$ cases both immediately give the claim, we're left to consider the case of $\lnot \lnot A \land \lnot \lnot B$. It's also worth remembering that we haven't used our $\lnot(A \land B)$ assumption yet!

Of course, it's [well known](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/636199/double-negation-distributes-over-conjunction) that $\lnot \lnot A \land \lnot \lnot B$ is equivalent to $\lnot \lnot (A \land B)$, and from $\lnot(A \land B)$ and $\lnot \lnot (A \land B)$ we can prove false, and from there, the claim.

As an aside, weak LEM is actually intuitionistically *equivalent* to $\lnot (A \land B) \to \lnot A \lor \lnot B$, and now that you've seen one direction, you might try to go the other way too!

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone wants to see how this is done without recourse to a Heyting algebra (as I was thinking, when I first asked it), one can use as a lemma that double negation distributes over implication intuitionistically ([Does double negation distribute over implication intuitionistically?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3753752/does-double-negation-distribute-over-implication-intuitionistically)), and then perform the following (at 14 we are using the lemma, but hopefully elsewhere what move we are making is clear) [image]